# Route from login page to root page doesn't work in Netlify

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, netlify

I have an admin panel. user can see the dashboard, after login. In the local host, it works well. But when I deployed it to Netlify, after showing the login page, and user login, a blank page appear.

I use react-router-dom v6.

```
function App() {
  const loginCtx = useContext(LoginContext);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
        <Routes>
          {!loginCtx.isLogin ? (
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          ) : (
            <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
              <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/customers" element={<Customers />} />
              <Route path="/customers/:customerId" element={<CustomerEdit />} />
              <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
              <Route path="/products/:productId" element={<ProductEdit />} />
            </Route>
          )}
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm useing redirects  `/*  /index.html   200` in `_redirects` file.

Comment: Instead of conditionally rendering routes you might find you have better luck using an auth layout route that redirects to a `"/login"` route rendering the `Login` component or allows access through to a routed component. If you need help with this I can provide an example.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it if you provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of conditionally rendering routes you might find you have better luck using an auth layout route that redirects to a `"/login"` route rendering the `Login` component or allows access through to a routed component.

Create an auth layout route that checks the `loginCtx.isLogin` value and conditionally renders an `Outlet` for nested `Route`s to be rendered into, or a redirect to the `"/login"` route.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const loginCtx = useContext(LoginContext);

  return loginCtx.isLogin
    ? <Outlet />
    : (
      <Navigate
        to="/login"
        replace
        state={{ from: location }} // <-- current location so login can redirect back is desired
      />
    );
};
```

Wrap the routes you want to protect with the new `AuthLayout` component, and move `Login` component into its own route.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
              <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/customers" element={<Customers />} />
              <Route path="/customers/:customerId" element={<CustomerEdit />} />
              <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
              <Route path="/products/:productId" element={<ProductEdit />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. but it doesn't work.

Comment: I figure out my Chart component was the problem, and now I want to find out how to fix it. If you can help me, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71837173/cahrtjs-and-react-chartjs-2-doesnt-work-when-i-deploy-react-app-to-netlify (I appreciate for your help)

Comment: I did wrong in importing chart code. Thank you so much for your attention and guidance.

Comment: @ZahraMirzaei Ok, cool. Glad to help. Cheers and good luck!